# DLP potential incident

Tags: email, email-attachments

A former employee has sent a credentials files to his personal email. After confronted he deleted it from his personal email. How to assure that he has not send it to another email from his personal email?
Any tips will be valuable.

Comment: This is not a programming question.  You could try asking on [Security.SE] but the answer will almost certainly be "you can't assure this, proceed on the assumption that the file is compromised".

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming.